# How to highlight Custom UIButton When tap in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton

I am trying to highlight a custom UIButton when i tapping like following picture.

[image]

I want to spread white light like above image.

Any property that i need to use for that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your xib->select button->Show your attribute inspector

set this property as in image below[image]

and by code

```
btn.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;
```

Hope it helps you..

Comment: Ok. i got it bro.. Thanks a lot and i need to wait 9 minutes to tick correct answer. :)